# Visa to Mexico for Belarus citizen with a permanent Uk residency

Tags: visas, mexico, uk-residents, belarusian-citizens

I am a Belarusian citizen, living in the UK on a permanent residency status. Do I need a visa to Mexico?

Answer (score 3):

Permanent residents of the UK do not require a visa to visit Mexico for stays of up to 180 days. You must be able to present a document proving your permanent residence to the airline at check-in and also at the Mexican immigration checkpoint (e.g. a [BRP](https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits)).

Relevant parts from the [Mexican immigration](https://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/paises-requieren-visa-para-mexico/) web site:

> No requerirá visa mexicana el extranjero que presente alguno de los siguientes documentos:
>
> a) Documento que acredite residencia permanente en Canadá, Estados Unidos de América, Japón, el Reino Unido de la Gran Bretaña e Irlanda del Norte, cualquiera de los países que integran el Espacio Schengen, así como en los países miembros de la Alianza del Pacífico (Chile, Colombia y Perú).

You also need a FMM (tourist card) but your airline will provide this to you to fill out. If you cross by land you will have to make sure to obtain one of these before passing the immigration checkpoint.